# Graphic Setup tune-up checklist

Tags: graphics-card, opengl, directx, 3d-graphics

I was trying to play the game [Warzone 2100](http://wz2100.net/) and the games runs fine, with nice speed, but the screen stays with a horizontal lines "flickering"...

My PC have a integrated GeForce Go 6100 vga. Ok, not a powerfull vga, but it's not the end of the world to run a "simple" game like this (compared with another games that ask you send your eyes to purchase a expensive vga).

So, I think that the problem can be of the configuration of my machine. I use it in first instance for programming jobs, so I underpay attention to video setup.

I would like about a checklist to know if my PC is "ready" to games. By example, I know that I need:

1. Lastest vga drivers
2. Updated DirectX and OpenGL

What you suggest? There is too some good programs to test performance and suggests improvements in the system?

Thank you!

PS: I'm using Windows 7